# Isset on multiple values

Tags: php, html, forms, post, isset

I want to check many values if are set at the same time. I read from the isset documentation that says `If multiple parameters are supplied then isset() will return TRUE only if all of the parameters are set. Evaluation goes from left to right and stops as soon as an unset variable is encountered.`

So why does my code always print the values sent and never prints 'no'?

PHP

```
if ( isset( $_POST['thread'],
        $_POST['winkey'],
        $_POST['dkey'],
        $_POST['winrew'],
        $_POST['drew'] )===true ) {
    echo $_POST['thread'];
    echo $_POST['winkey'];
    echo $_POST['dkey'];
    echo $_POST['winrew'];
    echo $_POST['drew'];
}
else echo 'no';
```

HTML

```
<form action="class.php" method="POST">
thread link:<br>
<input type="text" name="thread" >
<br>
win key:<br>
<input type="text" name="winkey" >
<br>
double key:<br>
<input type="text" name="dkey" >
<br>
winrew:<br>
<input type="text" name="winrew" >
<br>
double rew:<br>
<input type="text" name="drew" >
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="banlist" value="ban">Include banlist<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You don't really need to test them all. In fact in most cases just checking one or two of them from the mix is fine.

Comment: I do, my program requires all of them to be set.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek The principle of never trusting user input - since these are attack vectors for bots - should also require you to test them all.  Anything short of that is a security vulnerability, and your website will get hacked at some later date.

Comment: [Another similar question has better answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187066) that will also address the question here.  It was also asked before this one.  If I were to provide an answer here, I'd just link to some of the answers there.  So I would vote this as a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to check multiple $\_POST variable for existence using isset()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187066/how-to-check-multiple-post-variable-for-existence-using-isset)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as you submit your form, all the variables in `$_POST` that you mention, will be set. If a `POST` request is not made, none of them will be set.

I think you are looking for `empty()` instead to test if any of the variables is empty.

Comment: The problem is empty doesn't support multiple parameters, so if I have a big form I have to write for each of them.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc Yes, but I would guess you are doing some validation any way. You could also put the names of the required fields in an array and loop over that.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because when you POST the form, the values ARE set, even if you didn't put anything in the input fields. For those keys you would get an empty string (which would return TRUE for `isset()`).

You probably should be checking using `!empty()`.

An even better approach might be to use `filter_input_array()`. That could look something like this.

```
//define callback function to be used to check if value is empty
function empty_filter($var) {
    if(!empty($var)) return $var;
}

$filter_definitions = array(
    'thread' => array('filter'    => FILTER_CALLBACK,
                      'options'   => 'empty_filter',
                      'error_message'    => 'This field cannot be empty.'), // filter_var_array will ignore this, but you can specify messaging here.
    'winkey' => array('filter'    => FILTER_CALLBACK,
                      'options'   => 'empty_filter',
                      'error_message'    => 'This field cannot be empty.'),
    'dkey' => array('filter'    => FILTER_CALLBACK,
                      'options'   => 'empty_filter',
                      'error_message'    => 'This field cannot be empty.'),
    'winrew' => array('filter'    => FILTER_CALLBACK,
                      'options'   => 'empty_filter',
                      'error_message'    => 'This field cannot be empty.'),
    'drew' => array('filter'    => FILTER_CALLBACK,
                      'options'   => 'empty_filter',
                      'error_message'    => 'This field cannot be empty.')
);

$filtered_post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $filter_definitions, true);

// items not passing filter will show as NULL, so we check for NULL
if(in_array(NULL, $filtered_post)) {
    // you can walk through the filtered array an echo out error messages
    foreach($filtered_post as $key => $value) {
        if(is_null($value)) {
            echo $key . ': ' . $filter_definitions[$key]['error_message'] . '<br>';
        }
    }
} else {
   // validation passed
   // do whatever comes next
}
```

Note here that you can define a different filtering condition for each key in the input array, so for example you want to validate one field as email address, one as an IP address, one as a regular expression, or even your own custom validation, you can specify the validation criteria and do it all in one pass.

Answer (score 0):

when you submit form than values on action page gone.
that's mean something is going from input it could be empty strings but you can consider this empty strings like zero in number which has not value but have number. same in your case, values are going on action page that is why every time values print.

you can check now by opening action page in new tab when form will not submitted. no will be print that's mean values are not going on action page. your code should be as below.

```
if ( isset( $_POST['thread'],
    $_POST['winkey'],
    $_POST['dkey'],
    $_POST['winrew'],
    $_POST['drew'] )===true ) {
    if ($_POST['thread'] == "" and $_POST['winkey'] == "" and $_POST['dkey'] == "" and $_POST['winrew'] == "" and $_POST['drew'] == ""){
        echo "no";
    } 
    else{
            echo $_POST['thread'];
            echo $_POST['winkey'];
            echo $_POST['dkey'];
            echo $_POST['winrew'];
            echo $_POST['drew'];
    }

}
else echo 'no';
```